# Updating a large MySQL database using ASP.NET from Excel

Tags: asp.net, mysql

We have a web application with backend database in MySQL. The Master table has about 170000 records. The client feature allow him/her to upload an Excel sheet with identical columns as in Master with about updated 1000 records. The objective is to update the Excel Master table based on id column (existing at both end) however updating only few columns. Response time is a critical factor.

So what we have done in ASP.NET is as follows:

1. Upload the excel sheet onto the server
2. Create a datatable and update all the contents of Excel sheet in it
3. Now based on a column attribute query the Excel database and update the records one by one

Currently this process takes about 19 minutes to update about 1300 records. So how can we enhance the update speed?

We have also observed that MySql update query like the following also takes a lot of time:

```
update " + Session["Circle"].ToString() + ".retail n," + Session["Circle"].ToString() + ".upload o set n.VillageName=o.VillageName, n.TehsilName=o.TehsilName, n.DistrictName=o.DistrictName, where n.Retailer_MSISDN=o.Retailer_MSISDN;
```

Comment: Is the column Retailer_MSISDN indexed?

Comment: Why not use Excel's native connection tools to do it directly through Excel?  http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/excel-to-mysql/#!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Retailer_MSISDN` is unique and indexed. You can create an index for `Retailer_MSISDN` by:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table  
ADD INDEX Retailer_MSISDN(Retailer_MSISDN);
```

Doing look ups by indexed columns will decrease the time to do the look up.